# How do I create different delays when using methods for Java?

Tags: java, wait, chatbot, thread-sleep

I'm trying to make a chatbot with different wait times based on user/chatbot responses and I always have a delay even though I remove wait time from addTextUser or use different milliseconds.

```
public void addTextUser(String str){
    wait(1000); 
    dialog.setText(dialog.getText()+str);                       
}

public void addTextBot(String str){
    wait(2000); 
    dialog.setText(dialog.getText()+str);                       
}

public static void wait(int ms){
    try{
        Thread.sleep(ms);
    }
    catch(InterruptedException e){
    }
}
```

Current result is:

*wait 3 secs:* - **User**
*no wait* - **Bot**
*wait 3 secs:* - **User**
*no wait* - **Bot**

Expected result should be:

*wait 1 sec:* **User**
*wait 2 secs:* **Bot**
*wait 1 sec:* **User**
*wait 2 secs:* **Bot**

Comment: It looks like you are trying to put sleep() and wait() in the Swing or JavaFX update thread. That is not something that you should do, because it will delay your program in unpredictable ways.

Comment: BTW: You should not ignore the InterruptedException.

Comment: Generally speaking any UI and/or network interaction based system will use an event loop. That almost means you should **almost never** have actual `sleep` calls inside of your code. Instead you either schedule an event for when you want to act next or have some code that's running periodically check if it's past some time to act (basically building your own event queue).

Comment: @AndiCover mentioned already the wherever you have interrupted exception should add  ```Thread.currentThread().interrupt();```  in the handling block, because current thread should be aware that there is interrupted exception.  @Heinz Kabutz java champion also mentioned in his concurrency conference.

Comment: Even though I add `Thread.currentThread().interrupt();` in the catch exception remains the same, I think what @JoachimSauer said would be the only option, how can I build the scheduled task or even if I am already using Key events for the chat bot actions?